# datagrab moving from one site to another

Tags: datagrab, export, csv

I am trying to move the data from one site to another, I can import from datagrab but what is the best (quickest) way to get the data out of the site? CSV or feed - is there a way to auto generate these?

Comment: Are you moving data from one EE site to another EE site? What kind of websites are involved?

Comment: its all channels

Comment: I was asking because you could simply zip up all of the files, export the Database via PHPMyAdmin or the command line, migrate that to the new server, unzip, change the permissions, setup a new Database, import the old MySQL into that, and resetup your connections in the /system/config/database.php file then make sure your permissions are setup correctly.

Comment: yes is it a 2 way process so I am working locally trying to add features while the client updates their content on the current 'beta' site. I need to export their data so I can import it into mine then I can do a full export like you suggest, it is a commercial project so export-it looks good.

Comment: Okay yeah that's what I would suggest :) I wouldn't have marked Bluedreamer as the answer though since he didn't really answer the question...I did :) But whatevs yo! Let us know if you need anything else :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of addons that may help, http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ajw-export and 
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/export-it

I sometimes create a template to output data in CSV format, load up the template page then save the page as .csv ready for importing with Datagrab. This works fine for simpler data sets.